# PHP removing white spaces from link

Tags: php, sql, tablelayout, oracle-call-interface

[image]

I want to display table titles without white spaces from my SQL database using PHP. `$argument` is a query like (Select * from students):-

```
$stid = oci_parse($connect, $argument);
oci_execute($stid);
$ncols = oci_num_fields($stid);
for ($i = 1; $i <= $ncols; $i++) {
    $string = preg_replace('/\s+/','', oci_field_name($stid, $i));
    echo $string;
    <a href="?sort=     
        <?php echo oci_field_name($stid, $i);?>
        "><i class="fa fa-sort" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </a>
}
```

But function preg_replace doesn't remove spaces from my title and links. Anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: Display what is showing, I can't proccess the echo in my mind

Comment: Show us what's your input data & what kind of data you are expecting in the output?

Comment: instead of this:- `<?php echo oci_field_name($stid, $i);?>` use `<?php echo $string;?>`.Also try to use `str_replace(' ','',oci_field_name($stid, $i))`

Comment: Added img. I want remove white spaces from title PRZEWOŹNIK etc.

Comment: I tried str_replace(' ','',oci_field_name($stid, $i)) but doesn't work too.

Comment: have you tried the `trim()` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have newlines and spaces both there so do like below:-

```
$stid = oci_parse($connect, $argument);
oci_execute($stid);
$ncols = oci_num_fields($stid);
for ($i = 1; $i <= $ncols; $i++) {
    $string = trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', oci_field_name($stid, $i)));
    echo $string;
    <a href="?sort=<?php echo $string;?>"><i class="fa fa-sort" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </a>
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Now works. Whitespaces was on <?php echo $string;?>
        "> line as you can see

Comment: @Zomfire  glad to help you :):)

Answer (score 0):

try to use trim() function, 
doc: http://php.net/manual/pl/function.trim.php

Comment: I tried to use trim() and this solution doesn't work as well. I don't know why.

Comment: @Zomfire  it's not only spaces but also new line too